# Image format conversion from terminal?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, eps

Is there any way to convert image formats from Ubuntu terminal?

Particularly from eps to png/jpg or to any other formats.

Comment: Look at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php --- simply `apt-get install imagemagick`.

Comment: Rmano:thanx.....this is coool

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `imagemagick` command line tool

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

You can use it like this:

```
convert myfile.eps foo.png
```

Comment: I suggest to use the `-density` option also, e.g. `convert -density 150 myfile.eps foo.png`.  The default density is only 72 dpi, which looks chunky.

Comment: Also `mogrify` command is useful, instead `convert`. See `man mogrify` or search on Askubuntu

Comment: `convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy PDF @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.` - you will need to read this to overcome it https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180170/2324000

Answer (score 30):

For anyone who lands here trying to figure out how to work around ImageMagic's `convert: not authorized` without reverting the change that was made to the system-wide security policy to close a vulnerability, here's how to rasterize EPS files by calling Ghostscript directly:

```sh
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -r600 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=foo.png myfile.eps
```

- `-dSAFER` puts Ghostscript in a sandboxed mode where Postscript code can only interact with the files you specified on the command line. (Yes, the parts of EPS, PS, and PDF files that define the page contents [are in a turing-complete programming language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_NXz7I5dQc).)
- `-DBATCH` causes it to quit when it reaches the end of the input file, rather than switching to an interactive PostScript prompt.
- `-dNOPAUSE` prevents it from prompting to continue after each page
- `-dEPSCrop` asks for the rendered output to be cropped to the bounding box of the drawing rather than padded out to the declared page size (See [the manual](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#EPS_parameters) for details.)
- The `-r600` specifies the DPI you want to render at
- The `-sDEVICE` specifies the output format (See the [Devices section](https://ghostscript.com/doc/Devices.htm#PNG) of the manual for other choices.)

**UPDATE:** I've since learned that `-o foo.png` is a cleaner, easier-to-remember shorthand for `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=foo.png` so the better command would be this:

```sh
gs -dSAFER -dEPSCrop -r600 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o foo.png myfile.eps
```

The manual also mentions that, some day, they eventually hope to be able to make `-dSAFER` the default though, given backwards compatibility needs, who knows if that will ever happen.

Comment: `@ssokolow` Thanks for your help. This got my image converted!

Answer (score 0):

I convert .odg to .png by using Prt Scr key on keyboard then selecting the area I want to convert.  Fast & Safe.